# angularjs gantt hide specific hour column

Tags: angularjs, gantt-chart

Is it possible to hide specific hour column in angularjs-gantt chart.
Say I have:

```
headers="['month', 'day', 'hour']"
```

This will show all the hours from 0 through 24. But I only like to show working hours which is 8 to 19.

Also can i have provision to give specific width for each hour colomn, with some calculation on what hour is